# Set default tags in Django/Wagtail

Tags: python, django, tags, wagtail

I want to be able to set a list of default tags using Taggable Manager.

`city_region_tags = TaggableManager(through=CityRegionSnippetTag, blank=True)`

The `CityRegionTableSnippetTag` is -

```
class CityRegionSnippetTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = models.ForeignKey(
        'CityRegionSnippet',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tagged_city_region'
    )
```

Ideally I would pass a list of default tags e.g. 
`tag_list = ['Spatial Patterns', 'Functional dynamics', 'Social-eco dynamics', 'Global-local dynamics']` and so on.

Is there a way to do this?

I had a look at custom tagging here and doesn't appear to be what I want to do - (https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_tagging.html#)

Documentation on tags in forms shows what the tags would look like in a list but that is after user input. I want to be able to put these tags in before the user gets there from the `tag_list` - (https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#tags-in-forms)

Comment: Your question is already quite old, but I'm looking into the same topic and would like to know if you have found the answer for it? Thanks!